# Image Pattern Matching in SQL Server

Tags: c#, azure, windows-8, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

I have an metro app which takes a picture of a burning flame and sends it Azure. I am storing image directly in SQL Server table and not in BLOB because the image is generally < 100KB. The way I am  implementing it is the image is inserted into the table, and after successful insert a push notification is sent to client with a set of instructions which indicate action to be taken for a flame.

Now, I am researching how I can implement pattern matching in the SQL Server table.

The table already has 10 images and my app takes a picture, inserts it into table and tries to compare it and finds the closest match and based on the match the specific instructions will be sent to metro app.

IS there any framework which I can use to do this pattern matching in cloud and carry specific task based on this pattern matching?

Can anybody please help me with any info in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't recommend anything specific: Whatever app you find that will install and run in either a Windows or Linux virtual machine (or in a Windows VM in a Cloud Service, if the install can be automated and quick), should be ok. Just make sure whatever library you use doesn't rely on any specific GPU (since Azure doesn't offer GPU support today).

I saw another answer recommending a CLR procedure to process the images. I really wouldn't recommend that, as you're now stressing the CPU of your SQL Server, and that's not something that can easily be scaled out to multiple servers. And if you choose to use Windows Azure SQL Database, you won't have CLR as an option. You're better off placing processing in, say, a Cloud Service worker role, where you can scale out to any number of instances, and you can then use an Azure Queue to instruct the workers to perform specific comparisons / processing.

Comment: I didn't notice that Azure was the chosen DB, so I deleted my post.  In similar situations without Azure, I would advocate using CLR from SQL only to asynchronously kick off a worker thread on another machine. I agree completely that you don't want your SQL DB running .NET code and potentially holding locks until relatively complex image processing is completed.  Using CLR to initiate notifications is lightweight enough to run on your SQL server though, as long as they're processed elsewhere.

Comment: @David Thanks for the answer ,i now understand how i can implement the program in Azure but i am more interested to know if there is any pre existing library i can use for doing this pattern matching. I have very short time and resources and it is not possible for me to write an library from scratch. I need to use an existign library which has sufficent accuracy.